# Help understanding layout files and where action links to

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, reports

I'm working on creating a custom report and rather than just cut and paste code I'm trying to understand how magento layout files work better.

Magento 1.9
I'm looking at a report Products -> Most Viewed.

I've found the menu item added in

> app/code/core/Mage/Reports/etc/adminhtml.xml

Obviously I removed a lot to just show what I'm asking questions about.

```
<config>
    <menu>
        <report translate="title" module="reports">
            <children>
                <products translate="title" module="reports">
                    <children>      <!-- Menu Item -->
                        <viewed translate="title" module="reports">
                            <title>Most Viewed</title>
                            <action>adminhtml/report_product/viewed</action>
                        </viewed>
                    </children>
                </products>
            </children>
        </report>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Where it says:

```
<action>adminhtml/report_product/viewed</action>
```

I know that accesses

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Product
```

My question is, does the `/viewed` mean it opens `Viewed.php`, or subfolder `/Viewed`?

If the answer is it opens `Viewed.php`, what then opens the file `/Viewed/Grid.php`?

Answer (score 1):

It calls the `Viewed.php` file.

That file extends the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php` file's class.

In that file, you will find the `protected function _prepareLayout()` which uses the `setChild` method to assign the appropriate file as `Mage/Adminhtml/Block/***/Grid.php`

Answer (score 1):

Found this tutorial that helped me understand the magento file structure.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-3.html